# Can you delete specific lines in a batch file/ cmd program?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've made a program which needs Administrator privileges to copy itself to another folder. That's the reason i've added this (i found it on stackoverflow) to the beginning of my program:

```
@echo off

:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------
```

However after the program is copied to the folder i do not want this code anymore because it isn't required and it will still give pop ups.
My question is: Can this code somehow be deleted after one use of the program? 
All the code has to be done in the same batch file.

Thank you!

Comment: You want to delete the batch it self? try `del thebatchfile.bat` before the line exit /B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of copying the file to the new directory and deleting parts of the code afterwards, how about this:

Start your batch file, check for admin and if successful "write" the content to the destination directory simply skipping the lines you want to delete.

Something like this:

```
@echo off
SET targetfile=C:\new\folder\targetfile.bat    

:: BatchGotAdmin
REM your admin code here
:--------------------------------------

ECHO 1st line of your code>%targetfile%
ECHO 2nd line of your code>>%targetfile%
ECHO 3rd line of your code>>%targetfile%
REM ... your code ...
ECHO last line of your code>>%targetfile%
```

This way you will "create" the file in the target location.

Another option is to use a `FOR /F` loop to walk through your file, copy it line by line into a temp file, skip the "admin check" part, delete the the original file and rename the new file to the old name. This is also possible but it's really ugly. If you prefer this solution, tell me and I'll post some code. But beware! You won't like it! :D